# How to Put Data Inside of Specific Cells of Spreadsheet Using PHP

Tags: php, excel, file, csv, edit

For example, I want my `$cell1` PHP variable's data to be placed inside of cell `C19` of my spreadsheet, and `$cell2` to be placed inside of cell `B12`. Also, the spreadsheet I am using would already be created, so PHP would be pulling the spreadsheet file (e.g., spreadsheet.csv) and placing these variables inside of the above-said cells.

Is there any PHP code that will do this?

Comment: Asking for software/libraries is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB My apologies, I am looking for code that will do this then.

Comment: and we are not here to write code for you. that's "do my job for me". you write code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the productive feedback, Marc!

Comment: You can use phpexcel. [download and documentation](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @RafaelShkembi Put your comment into an answer, and I will mark it as Best Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use phpexcel. [Download and documentation](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful suggestion.